# What does 'pull it off' mean in the context?

Tags: phrase-usage

I saw this sentence from a comment for [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/ivanka-trump-pays-tribute-japanese-153825961.html).

> She can afford it and she has the body to easily **pull it off**. The liberals hate her because she's attractive, smart and takes care of herself.

I know 'pull off' could mean 'succeed in achieving something'. But I am not sure how it could fit in this context, and I need some explanation based on the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pull something off means not only to succeed in doing something but often to succeed in a way that requires something not everyone has - the “something” can be anything from courage to physique.

So if Ivanka can “pull off” a dress, it means she can manage to look good in it, in this case because she’s rich enough to have it custom-made for her and has the right physique. Or, bluntly put, while she looks good in the dress, someone shorter and chubbier might look like an oversized tea cozy. (No offense, we all have our strengths and weaknesses.)